# A function is continuous at all non-cluster points

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A theorem says that for any function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and for any $c$ that is not a cluster point of $S$, $f$ is continuous at $c$.

My idea of the proof: Since $c$ is not a cluster point of $S$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap S=\emptyset$. Choose $\delta$ to be such, and let $x\in S$ be such that $|x-c|<\delta$. But then such $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, which is impossible. So there does not exist $x\in S$ with $|x-c|<\delta$. Hence (vacuously) $f$ is continuous at $c$.

But in the notes the proof goes something like, for all $\epsilon>0$, $|f(x)-f(c)|=|f(c)-f(c)|=0<\epsilon$, hence $f$ is continuous at $c$. This doesn't really make sense to me because clearly neither $x$ nor $c$ are in the domain of the function, so it makes no sense to talk about $f(x)$ and $f(c)$.

Comment: That $c$ is not a cluster point means that you can isolate $c$ in a ball. Therefore the only point is $c$. I don't know why you assume that $c$ is not in $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong from the start, when you write that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap S=\emptyset$. That intersection contains $c$, at least (and it is equal to $\{c\}$ if $\delta$ is small enough).

Now, concerning the notes that you mentioned, your coments make no sense, because you state that “neither $x$ nor $c$ are in the domain of the function”. Yes, they are.

Comment: Why can we find a $\delta>0$ such that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap S =\{c\}$? If $S$ is also an open interval, then we can't have a singleton intersection, because the union of two non-disjoint open intervals is an open interval, and an open interval is a connected set.

Comment: @SidCaroline If $S$ was an open interval, then it would have no non-cluster point, right?!

Comment: Take $S=(-1,1)$ and $c=5$, then the set of cluster points of $S$ is $[-1,1]$, and clearly $c$ is not a cluster point of $S$? No never mind, we assumed that $c\in S$ in the beginning.

Comment: @SidCaroline You are misunderstanding the statement of the theorem. What it says is that if $S\subset\mathbb R$, if $f$ is a function from $S$ into $\mathbb R$ and if $c\in S$ is a non-cluster point, of $f$, then $f$ is continuous at $c$. Otherwise, it would make no sense. We only say that a function is continuous (or not) at a point $c$ when $c$ belongs to the domain of $f$.